# Multiple namespaces; trying to call method in one, passing output to another method within 3rd method

Tags: methods, clojure, namespaces

I've got a namespace implementing a multimethod like this:

```
(ns a)
(defmulti funca (fn [system data] system))
(defmethod funca :add-z 
  [system data] 
  (conj data {:z 26}))
```

I've got a 2nd namespace implementing a different multimethod:

```
(ns b)
(defmulti funcb (fn [system data new-element] system))
(defmethod funcb :add-element
  [system data new-element]
  (conj data new-element))
```

I've got a 3rd namespace defined as

```
(ns c
  (:require [a :refer [funca]]
            [b :refer [funcb]]))
```

I want to create a method in namespace c, which I can invoke as e.g.

```
(funcc (funca :add-z {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
       (funcb :add-element {:y 25}))
```

This should take the result of `(funca :add-z {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})` (which would be `{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :z 26}`) and use that result as input to `(funcb :add-y-and-count-elements {:y 25})`, which would then return the result `{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :y 25 :z 26}`.

In trying to define `funcc`, I'm trying things like

```
(ns c
  (:require [a :refer [funca]]
            [b :refer [funcb]]))
(defn funcc [funca funcb]
  (partial funcb funca))
```

or

```
(defn funcc [funca funcb]
  (funcb (funca)))
```

or

```
(defn funcc [funca funcb]
  (-> funca
      funcb))
```

but when run any of these in a REPL and invoke funcc, I'm getting

> Wrong number of args (2) passed to: b/eval19367/fn

What's the correct syntax for defining `funcc`, so that it can take the output of the first parameter passed to it, use it as the input for the second parameter passed, then return the result?

Answer (score 0):

> This should take the result of `(funca :add-z {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})` (which would be `{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :z 26})` and use that result as input to `(funcb :add-y-and-count-elements {:y 25})`, which would then return the result `{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :y 25 :z 26}`

According to this description your `funcc` actually accepts just one argument (the result of call to `funca`) so it should be defined like this:

```
(defn funcc [data]
  (funcb :add-element data {:y 25}))
```

and call it:

```
(funcc (funca :add-z {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}))
```

If you always want to call `funcc` with the result of `funca` applied to `add-z` with some data you could change it to:

```
(defn funcc [data]
  (let [result-from-funca (funca :add-z data)]
    (funcb :add-element result-from-funca {:y 25})))
```

and call it:

```
(funcc {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the as-> macro

```
(as-> {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} data
   (funca :add-z data)
   (funcb :add-element data {:y 25}))
```

If `funca` and `funcb` accepted data in first argument position, you could use the `->` arrow. If the both accepted data in last position, you could use the `->>` and even `comp`, e. g.

```
(def funcc (comp (partial funcb :add-element {:y 25}) 
                 (partial funca :add-z)))
```

Depending on what kind of transformations will become most useful for the functions you are writing, design their signatures around Clojures common composition tools which are arrows and comp.